# piping crunch output in random order not from file

Tags: kali-linux

a similar question was asked and answered here [Random character generation - with random output!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162755/random-character-generation-with-random-output/162786#162786?newreg=b2f55160834a4848b6d0809a6460cea6)
but when piping crunch to hashcat or aircrack or many others you end up with lists too big to save as files and then sort so you run the list "on the fly" but that is sort or revers sort output. in this way it takes days to populate 9 characters beyond its initial aaaaaaaaa or zzzzzzzzz im looking of an initial qlwuandoe  and then any other of the possible combinations but  qlwuandoe and so on until there are none. is this possible with or without crunch?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, maybe because English is not my first language. Do you want `crunch 9 9 -s qlwuandoe`?

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski no crunch outputs aaa aab aac aad with -i its aad aac aab aaa i want random  aac aab aad aaa except character set "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ~!@#$%^&*()_+" and a password length of 9 or more characters.

Comment: I totally don't know what your comment has to do with `qlwuandoe` that appears in the question and *seems* important.

Comment: Kamil Maciorowsk qlwuandoe is just a random alpha 9 length password that crunch would generate  but it would take weeks to get there  i want to start there and goto the next one also random . and im also looking for alpha numeric and symbols so as a file its petabytes in size......

Comment: What you want is not possible.  Generating random strings is no problem, but keeping track of which ones have already been generated is going to require disk space and/or RAM **plus** extra processing and I/O to check every time a new string is generated.  And randomising the order of a list requires that the entire list already exist.  i.e. no matter what you do, it's still going to take petabytes of RAM (yeah, sure, you don't have that) or disk (equally unlikely).

Comment: I answered the linked question. See if [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/724051/108618) may help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks kas Kas? and Kamil Maciorowski it isnt possible to have both no textfile and a random output of that list if it is being generated and piped directly to an application. Kamil sorry i cant express it any more clearly than random output without having to save it as a file first then randomizing. the text file in question is 7 or 8 thousand PETABYTES in size so you understand why saving it first is an issue.

Comment: Now it really seems to me your question is a duplicate of the linked one. My answer there is the best I can give you at the moment.

Comment: @  Kamil Maciorowski it is and it is not .with crunch you can start at either end and go or start at a random place and continue from there . this is fine for crunch 1-9   but crunch 8-64 is too big to save  therefore it cant be randomized,  as per your answer  smart password starts in the middle then goes to each end or random ...starting in the middle and progressing  klmnnop  or kjihgfe  isnt useful but starting in the middle and randomly going to the next password might just get lucky  as is your wait 9 months or so to populate  beyond aaaaaaaa to baaaaaaaa  or the same if you -i

Comment: "might just get lucky" – Or unlucky. Randomness ("scatter gun") would give you an advantage if by trying a password you could tell if you are "near" the right one. But it's never the case, a password that differs by one character is as wrong as "totally" wrong one. Besides, *if* you could tell, then advancing by a fixed step until you are "near" would be a good strategy without randomness. My method gives you the same *expected* time of success as a random sequence, no matter if the actual password has been chosen according to some strategy or not.

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski "scatter gun" as you call it is precisely why shot guns are used they throw a lot of lead all around the target some miss some hit. crunch works in a linear fashion and requires you wade through large amounts of  unlikely of password candidates aaa aab aac  before getting into more likley candates of dzw or hdt or ... spending 9 months random scattergun has a higher probability than aaa aab aac aad ....for 9 months just to get to baaaaaaa or at least that is my opinion , statistics and probability has an answer but i work on gut feelings.anyway thanks for the input